# MacBook Pro retina 2013 with Yosemite 10.10.3: Severe Wi-Fi issues only on main account

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, macbook, osx-yosemite

In the last few weeks my MacBook Pro has developed increasingly severe Wi-Fi problems. At first it would drop connection every 10 minutes or so, but now it cannot find a network at all. In fact, the whole Wi-Fi interface has now become unresponsive. I am unable to toggle the Wi-Fi on/off from the menu or terminal, and the tray icon is sluggish.

I have tried a number of fixes found around the internet, including [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154139/my-new-macbook-pro-wont-keep-its-wi-fi-connection), the same things [this guy tried](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31360/severe-wifi-dropping-on-macbook-pro-have-to-restart-to-turn-back-on) and other diagnostics, etc etc. Nothing has made any difference so far.

However, the most notable thing I have observed is that these problems extend only to my main user account. To my suprise, logging into my guest account, I found that the Wi-Fi and associated interface was in perfect working order. Side note: internet connectivity to personal hotspot via Bluetooth is fine.

Now that I have witnessed it working fine on my guest account I cannot imagine it being a hardware issue. Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be interesting to enable full Wi-Fi debug logging with `/usr/libexec/airportd debug +AllVendor +AllDriver +AllUserland`, and compare what logs you get with the problem account vs. another account. Note that this logging change doesn't survive reboot, so you'll have to re-issue that command if you reboot. It would also be interesting to know if Wi-Fi works fine when Bluetooth is off. Also watch Console.app's "All Messages" log for other indications of things going wrong when you have the Wi-Fi problems. BTW, by "tray icon", do you mean the Wi-Fi Menu Extra?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. Firstly, on the main account wifi works at no time, bluetooth on or off. I have turned on debugging - which log am I looking for? There is something called wifi.log in console which is my best guess. By the tray icon I mean the "show wifi status in menu bar" icon. Nothing so far is apparent from the All Messages log, but i'll update if I see anything.

Comment: Note, I am seeing a whole bunch of "_handlelinkEvent: Got an error trying to query WiFi for power. Resetting state variables." entries in the wifi.log from the past few days.

Comment: I'm struggling with the exact same issue on a 2011 MBP. I had the airport card replaced, but it didn't solve the problem, so it might indeed be a software problem...

Comment: I tried switching to guest account, it didn't help either. For me, rebooting (and sometimes sleeping & waking) makes Airport work again for a while.

Comment: What does the network tab in activity monitor show?  Are there any mysterious processes showing heavy usage?

Comment: @BonsaiOak No. Also, upgrading to El Capitan didn't help either. Related link https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5983625?tstart=0 suggests reinstalling from scratch, might be worth a try...